# Silverstripe: Extend CMS Interface LeftAndMain

Tags: silverstripe

I'm following the instructions [on the Silverstripe site](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/howto/extend-cms-interface) to a T with no luck.

The new LeftAndMain.ss is just not being ran. Is the documented approach incorrect or is there a different way of extending the CMS interface?

Comment: Have you tried the silverstripe forums?  It may take a day but they have the specialized knowledge.

Comment: Yes i also experienced that overriding admin templates doesnt really work in SS3. Did you take the zzz_admin approach?

Comment: @ivoba Yep, I created a zzz_admin module as suggested in the Silverstripe article but it just doesn't seem to pickup the new LeftAndMain.ss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out, the instructions are a little inaccurate.

Firstly, I forgot I was on a master branch, so essentially SS 3.1 and the [instructions](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/howto/extend-cms-interface) are slightly different but still kind of wrong.

The instructions tell you to:

> Refresh the CMS interface with admin/?flush=all

But this wasn't doing anything for me, I had to do `?flush=all` on the root. So in my case: `http://ss.dev/?flush=all`

After flushing from the root everything worked as it should.